# I want to know the difference between './' and '/'

Tags: javascript, url

```
var Cart = require('/model/cartSchema');

var Cart = require('./model/cartSchema');
var Cart = require('../model/cartSchema'); 
var Cart = require('model/cartSchema');
```

I want to know the difference about the code above.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Cart = require('/model/cartSchema');
```

The above will start at the root of the domain, for example it will find `http://www.example.com/model/cartSchema`

```
var Cart = require('./model/cartSchema');
var Cart = require('model/cartSchema');
```

The above mean the same thing as each other, and will find it based on the **current** location of the file

```
var Cart = require('../model/cartSchema');
```

The above means that the file will be found starting at a location one above the current one.  For example, if you're in `http://www.example.com/one/two/` then it will look for the file `http://www.example.com/one/model/cartSchema`

---

As correctly mentioned by @Vishwanath, this can be effected by the use of the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag. Easier to quote from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) than write my own description...

> The HTML Base Element () specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one  element in a document.

You use it like this (note, only one of them!) in the `<head>` of your page

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
<base target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com/">
```

Comment: You should also mention baseUrl.

Comment: Well, I was talking about this http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl . But having information of base tag is also useful. :)

Comment: Sorry @Vishwanath, but how on earth was I supposed to know about a setting in a library that you never mentioned and I've never even heard of?!

Comment: My mistake. maybe thats not even relevant here. because question doesnt mention about requireJS. I just assumed that. My bad...